# Immediately write logging info when logging to a file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I have a python script running in the background.
The script uses logging to write information to a file.
However, it seems that there is a write buffer and I don't seem able to flush it right away and I am only able to see the info, when I stop the script.

The logger is initialised as follows

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
f_handler = logging.FileHandler('test.log')
f_format = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
f_handler.setFormatter(f_format)

logger.addHandler(f_handler)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

The info is written here:

```
logger.info('starting top of the hour')
```

I also tried adding a call to flush:

```
logger.info('starting top of the hour')
f_handler.flush()
```

How can I change the code such that I will be able to read the file as soon as the logger.info is executed?

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour isn't really related to logging, but to how files are handled in general. Whether `flush()` causes a write depends on your operating and file system. So the best chance is to first `flush()` to unbuffer the stream and than tell the OS to actually write:

```
import os
import logging

# set up your logger and handler here

logger.info('starting top of the hour')
f_handler.flush()
os.fsync(f_handler.stream.fileno())
```

If you don't want to manually do this everytime you write a log this can be hidden by using a logging adapter.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work either :(

Comment: You should add what operating system, what file system and how you are running the script to the question, because if this isn't working either, your problem isn't in python.

Comment: It's on MacOs and RaspiOs